# Can DI containers be used as an alternative to session state?

Tags: dependency-injection

Let's say I have an ITree interface that is injected into TreeStuffController.  Building the tree is an expensive operation, so I don't want the container to have to rebuild a Tree for each webrequest.

This sounds like it would be a case for SINGLETON life cycle, but what if each user had a unique tree?  Is there such a thing as SINGLETON PER USER?

I essentially want the controller to get a Tree object that is retrieved from persistence based upon the user and for that Tree to live for every request until the user performs some action (say they logout) or the object expires after x minutes (subsequent requests would restart the x minute timer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could definitely write some code in your application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) where you look up the user's tree when you know who the user is.

In chapter 8 in [my book](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236), I describe this as the lifetime style **Session Request Context**, but I also warn against it, as it can give your system problems with capacity. [Release It!](http://amzn.to/11Kmrb2) explains why session state in general is bad for a system's capacity.

You may also have the problem with session state that if you have more than a single server, you'll need to synchronize session states across all servers.

Still, as you describe the problem, if building the tree is *very expensive*, or if speed is more important than capacity, then Session Request Context may be worth looking into. Still, as with everything related to performance: **measure it**, don't attempt to reason about it.

That said, the following DI Containers have built-in support for Session Request Context:

- StructureMap
- Spring.NET (limited)

Apart from those, the following containers enable you to write custom lifetimes:

- Castle Windsor
- Unity

Comment: I assume you are referring to HttpSession scoping for SM?  The obvious thing to do would be to fix the "cost" for the operation, but I'm kind of limited at the moment to do such a thing.

Comment: Don't Ninject and Autofac support writing custom lifestyles? Simple Injector sure does.

Comment: Don't know about Ninject. Autofac had lifetime *scopes* when I looked at, but you couldn't write your own from scratch; this may have changed in the last few years, though...

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but that being said....

I think it might be better to inject a tree factory and store the newly created tree in the session object if it is already null.

If I wanted to do the same thing for global shared objects, I could either use a singleton or for consistency use the Application variable.

When I have the luxury of making the build-tree operation less expensive, it would be a simple matter to update the property accordingly.  Thoughts?

Comment: That sounds like the same approach as the **Session Request Context** I describe in my answer. Whether you use a DI Container to store objects in the application session, or whether you store object in session 'by hand', the result is the same.

Comment: Per our conversation, I'm starting to think that a DI container should be used **sparingly**.  I'd rather not too much 'magic' be hidden from view.